# chained class methods overwriting each other when only one is set

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I have created chained methods across a set of classes, but when I set values for the last link in the chain, it is overwriting value in what I thought were separate instances within the class chain.

For example:

```
sub0.one.some.a.time_t.raw = 1
sub0.one.some.b.time_t.raw = 2
```

But:

```
print sub0.one.some.a.time_t.raw
```

returns `2` (not `1`, as set above)

```
print sub0.one.some.b.time_t.raw
```

returns `2`

Code is below. `Sub0` is the top level in the chain, `Sub4` is the lowest. I add instances of classes as methods within the class by using the `type()` method.

Why isn't `sub0.one.some.a.time_t.raw` returning `1`, as I've set it? Isn't it a separate instance of all classes in the chain?

```
class Sub4(object):
    pass

class Sub3(object):
    pass

class Sub2(object):
    pass

class Sub1(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config_field = config['flag']

class Sub0(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config


sub4_methods = ['raw']
Sub4 = type("Sub4", (Sub4, ), { sub4:None for sub4 in sub4_methods})

sub3_methods = ['time_t']
Sub3 = type("Sub3", (Sub3, ), { sub3:Sub4() for sub3 in sub3_methods})

sub2_methods = ['a', 'b']
Sub2 = type("Sub2", (Sub2, ), { sub2:Sub3() for sub2 in sub2_methods})

sub1_methods = ['all', 'some']
Sub1 = type("Sub1", (Sub1,), { sub1:Sub2() for sub1 in sub1_methods})

configs = {
    "one": { "flag": True },
    "two": { "flag": False },
    }
Sub0 = type("Sub0", (Sub0,), { k:Sub1(v) for (k,v) in zip(configs.keys(), configs.values())})

#create class instance
sub0 = Sub0(configs)

#set values
sub0.one.some.a.time_t.raw = 1
sub0.one.some.b.time_t.raw = 2

#both of these return 1, even though they are set to 1 & 2 respectively
print sub0.one.some.a.time_t.raw
#returns 1

print sub0.one.some.b.time_t.raw
#returns 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling `type` here? It sounds like you might not know what the tools you're using are actually supposed to do.

Comment: I'm using `type` to create arbitrary methods (see *_methods lists) that are instances of another class, while inheriting any preset methods in the base class. How else would one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I add instances of classes as methods within the class by using the `type()` method.

That is not what `type` does. `type` makes an entirely new class. Even if you're aware of that (you don't seem to be), it's a bizarre and unsuitable choice for what you're trying to do.

> Isn't it a separate instance of all classes in the chain?

No. All objects in this attribute chain are shared.

If you want `Sub0` instances to have `Sub1` objects as attributes and `Sub1` objects to have `Sub2` objects as attributes, etc., do it the normal way, with `__init__`:

```
class Sub0(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = Sub1({"flag": True})
        self.two = Sub1({"flag": False})

class Sub1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.all = Sub2()
        self.some = Sub2()
...
```

If you want to define your attribute names with lists, you can do that using `setattr` in `__init__`:

```
class Sub1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for name in ['all', 'some']:
            setattr(self, name, Sub2())
```